# Unable to get relatedTo working on an ElementCriteriaModel

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, baseelementmodel

In a plugin I am trying to get Users related to other Users:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
$criteria->group = 'partners';
$criteria->relatedTo = [
  'sourceElement' => $someUserId
];

$result = $criteria->find();
```

I can see data in the relations table where `sourceId` is set to the value of `$someUserId` but I get nil results from `$criteria->find()`.

I've tried passing in a `UserModel`, the user ID (as shown above) and changing `sourceElement` to `targetElement` and `element` all with no success.

What have I missed here?

======EDIT======

It seems I can get what I need by doing this:

```
$user = craft()->users->getUserById(someUserId);
$relatedUsers = $user->partners;
```

This works but I'd like to understand what's wrong with the original code above. `partners` is the name of the relationship field on the source element as well as the name of the user group that that field targets.